# How to get extension and name of email attachment using PHP

Tags: php, imap, php-5.5

I was working with PHP imap functions to get email attachments using `imap_fetchstructure`.

In one case i came across one file name with `‘?Windows-1252?Q?PDS=5FPIMCO_Capital_Securities_Fund_=97_Wholesale_Class.?= =?Windows-1252?Q?pdf?=`
due to which I was unable get correct file name and extension.

Can any one help me to get file name and extension in this case